# Windows 8.1 Does not Detect Bluetooth Headset

Tags: windows-8, audio, drivers, bluetooth, headphones

I have the [Motorola S11 Flex HD](http://www.motorola.com/us/accessories/music/wireless-headphones/s11-hd/m-S11-HD.html) wireless Bluetooth headset which I have had connected to a Windows 8.1 Pro x64 machine with an [Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 + Bluetooth for Desktop](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-7260-bluetooth-desktop.html) card. This **worked great** for two months, then **stopped the other day** whenever I unplugged the machine to move it.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

---

## What I Know

- The **Bluetooth hardware in the machine is not loose from transportation**, as I opened up the machine ensured all connections were tight after transport.
- The **headset connects to** and sounds great when connected to **other devices**.
- The machine will eventually discover but **often drop connections** to other Bluetooth devices.
- The headset **works fine** whenever I dual boot into **Ubuntu** on the same machine.

---

## What I've Tried

1. **Updating** the [Intel Bluetooth drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24681/Intel-PROSet-Wireless-Software-for-Bluetooth-technology-for-Windows-8-1-64-bit-WP-).
2. **Removing all Bluetooth devices** from the Device Manager. This includes uninstalling any associated drivers.
3. **Remove the [Microsoft Bluetooth stack](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/811805).** This was short lived, as I had to restore the registry after it went corrupt from this.
4. **Ensured** all Bluetooth services are running.
5. **Updated** Windows with the latest updates.

---

## Here is what Happened

1. The device would **connect after many tries** with poor sound quality.
2. The Windows Bluetooth interface would always **fail to remove** the paired headset.
3. Uninstalled via Device Manager.
4. Scanning for hardware changes always **brings the powered off/disconnected headset back again**.
5. Devices and Printers screen now **displays a generic audio icon**, instead of the headset's icon.
6. **Does not work at all** now.

[image]

---

## Misc. Screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So it is a headset. Do you see one or two devices in Playback Devices? I have a [jam Transit](http://www.jamaudio.com/headphones/jam-transit-bluetooth-headphones) bluetooth headset and I see two devices. Headset  and Headphones. The Headset Properties under Advance settings are showing the grayed out setting "1 channel, 16 bit, 8000 Hz, Telephone quality) and the sound is horrible :) But if I select the Headphones as default device the sound is okay as the settings are 2 channel, 16 bit, 44100 Hz, CD quality. As to why they disconnect - no clue. See next comment for rest...

Comment: ..continued - Try to: remove the headset from bluetooth devices (unpair), uninstall all bluetooth drivers, remove all bluetooth devices, restart the computer and reinstall everything. Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow these steps in order:

1. Be sure that latest drivers for Bluetooth are installed.
2. Be sure that your Windows is up-to-date.
3. Check [this document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/980396) and apply the "hot fix" provided by Microsoft.
4. Try to install latest "Broadcam" [drivers](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php).
5. Try to install "Toshiba Bluetooth drivers" (use your favorite search engine to obtain it). This step solves Bluetooth issues on Windows in most cases in my experience.